# How to open a modal in a div which already has a controller (AngularJs)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, controller, modal-dialog

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <div id="result_1" class="result">
            <p class="title" ng-repeat="item in result | filter: query">
                <span class="ic"><b>{{item.name}}</b></span>
                <a href="#" class="ic1">Click for details...</a>
            </p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
     </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

this is a part of my first Ionic project, i'm new in this framework and AngularJs, so I have a controller which searchs for data in a json file.

I need to open a modal when user clicks on

`<a href="#" class="ic1">Click for details...</a>`

but when I searched about it, I figured out that I need another controller for creating a modal.

I already have a controller in my whole page, how can I add another controller to that specific line? Or do you know any other way to create a modal without using another controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-item>
  <div id="result_1" class="result">
      <p class="title" ng-repeat="item in result | filter: query">
          <span class="ic"><b>{{item.name}}</b></span>
          <br>
          <br>
          <span ng-click="popUp()" class="ic1">Click for details...</span>
      </p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

script:

- using $ionicPopup

  ```
  $scope.popUp = function() {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'More Details...',
          template: 'decription', // templateUrl:'myModalContent.html'
          buttons: [{
              text: '<b>OK</b>',
              type: 'button-assertive'
          }]
      });
   };
  ```

check this link for [Details](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/)

- using Ui bootstrap

  ```
  $scope.popUp = function() {

  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html'
      resolve: {
          data: function() {
              return $scope.data;
          }
      }
  });
  ```

  }

There are many options you can pass. You can give a controller for your pop up too.
check this link for [ui.bootstrap.modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: where should i insert that script? to my controller? anywhere in my `app.js`? or directly to my index.html in `<script></script>` tags?

Comment: Inside the controller of particular view where you wrote ng-click = "popUp()" and data to the pop up modal can be provided using resolve(If you have any data to pass to modal)

Comment: sometimes using ui bootstrap may give unexpected errors. better try to use $ionicPopup